# If barometer length is 10 meter long, would mercury still be 77 cm?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

The barometer length is around 1 meter and length to Hg column tells the pressure in room. Suppose if we have 10 meter long barometer with diameter of regular barometer, would it still show 77 cm? Need complete proof of it? Won't it have some other phenomenon coming in play due to height?

In short what is the impact if width/height ratio is very large. Please feel free to share if there is any reference material or research paper for this phenomenon.

Comment: Why would you think that the length of the barometer influences the height of the liquid?

Comment: @Ashutosh Nigam, have you tried anything? I dont think that the length of barometer influences the reading at all.

Comment: I deleted some, shall we say, overly unpleasant comments and their responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the length would very obvious the same .As the length of column $h$ is given by 
    h*density of Hg*g=Atm pressure outside
for fact that atmosphere pushes the mercury up until the column weight balance the force of atmosphere. I would like  Under what circumstances you are asking such Question

If you think theoretically the length of barometer is same (length shorter than 77cm is much reasonable question).but yeah I suggest you to look for what mercury vapor above the Hg can do to it (as you are varying volume above it)but I really don't believe anything reasonable will occur. Moreover it include time factors,to attain equilibrium. I am not sure but you can check it. Please share the result here if you got it.

Comment: The diameter is kept same as usual diameter but the height is 10 times or more.